# Responsive CSS viewport tag

Tags: html, css

I'm learning about the responsive `CSS` styling. I'm trying the example code on the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_webpage) but the `viewport` tag doesn't seem to work. When i change the `initial-scale` value or the `content` from `width=device-width` to for. e.g. `300` NOTHING happens! I've tested the code on both my desktop `FireFox` and `Opera` browsers...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
}

.menu {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.main {
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h1>Chania</h1>
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>The Flight</li>
    <li>The City</li>
    <li>The Island</li>
    <li>The Food</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h1>The City</h1>
  <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include a complete example of the failing code in the question.

Comment: @DBS Here You ere, but the code is available in the link I've embedded as well:-)

Comment: that intial-scale is for mobile browsers. For moile devices you have a difference between hardware pixels (physical pixels) and software pixels (css pixels). Most higher resolution devices have a 2:1 hardware to software pixel ratio. `initial-scale` will coutner that default devcie setting and change the ratio to 1:1 which is also default by normal desktop browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viewport mode is mostly used for mobile browsers. It is normal that nothing changes in desktop versions.

Comment: ok. I understand , but can You tell me WHY doesn't it ALSO works in the `Firefox`'s `Responsive Design Mode`?

Comment: Viewport It is used to enable or disable zoom in mobile view. What exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: As I've stated when I change the zoom value in the Firefox mobile emulation mode (Responsive Design Mode) the page zoom DOESN'T change!

Comment: can i try from this phone? I'm not so sure about mobile emulation mode. If it's live at an address, you can forward it to me. I am happy to assist.

Answer (score -1):

You should include @media queries in your page.
For e.g

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     /*CSS goes here*/
}
```

Check this https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_mediaquery

Comment: You miss the question. Nowhere in the question eh asks about media queries or an use-case that would require it. The question soley was about `viewport mode` and what it is supposed to do.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).